# Can someone explain how to correctly pass a tuple as an input variable to fsolve in Python without encountering a NameError?

Tags: python, arguments, fsolve

I am using Python.

I am trying to pass a tuple as an input variable ('myvar') to a function, which I then solve. The error message I receive is

NameError: name 'myvar' is not defined

Here the (minimal) snippet of the code I tried:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
vss = ('myvar')

def f_nb(*vss):
    nb= 0.8 - myvar
    return nb

def tryit(xx):
    myvar = xx
    zz= f_nb(myvar)
    return zz

solz = fsolve(tryit, (0.2))

solz
```

Comment: Where is defined `fsolve` ?

Comment: What tuples? `('myvar')` is a parenthesized string; `('myvar', )` is a tuple containing a single string. Also, why does `f_nb` take arbitrary positional arguments when you only want one specific named parameter? That said, you can define `myvar, *_ = args` inside the function to unpack the arguments.

Comment: I included arbitrary positional arguments for generality. Your proposed solution works. Thank you.